# Connect Quorum nodes to Ethereum

Tags: quorum

At Quorum network, we can submit public transactions within Quorum nodes. Are we able to connect Quorum nodes to Ethereum and allow those public transactions go to public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Not directly. The consensus mechanism is too different.

You could conceivably run both kinds and nodes and you can create bridge services that use provable event emissions from one chain to trigger transactions on the other.

Hope it helps.